Is the limit of the recurrent sequence negative?(Provided it exists)
[I rephrased the previous question to make it clearer]
Suppose $X$ is a discrete random variable with support on the natural number $\mathbb{N}$, we have a sequence $\{h_k\}$ denoting the probability of each outcome: $h_k= Pr[X=k], k=0,1,2,\cdots$, such a sequence satisfies $h_k > 0 \; \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sum_{k} h_k=1$.
Furthermore, given two initial values $f_0$ and $f_1$, we can use the following recurrence relationship to determine the whole sequence $\{f_k\}$
$\begin{align*}
f_2 \frac{h_1}{h_2+h_1} + f_0 \frac{h_0}{h_0} = f_1 
& \Rightarrow f_2 = \frac{h_1+h_2}{h_1}(f_1 - f_0) \\
f_3 \frac{h_2}{h_3+h_2}+ f_1 \frac{h_1}{h_1+h_0} = f_2 & \Rightarrow f_3 = \frac{h_2+h_3}{h_2}\left(f_2 - \frac{h_1}{h_1+h_0}f_1\right) \\
\vdots \\
f_k \frac{h_{k-1}}{h_{k}+h_{k-1}}+ f_{k-2} \frac{h_{k-2}}{h_{k-2}+h_{k-3}} = f_{k-1} & \Rightarrow f_k = \frac{h_{k}+h_{k-1}}{h_{k-1}}\left(f_{k-1} - \frac{h_{k-2}}{h_{k-2}+h_{k-3}}f_{k-2}\right) \\
\vdots
\end{align*}$
And by taking $f_1 = f_0*\frac{h_0+h_1}{h_0}$, we will have $f_k=f_0 \frac{h_k + h_{k-1}}{h_0}$, and hence $\lim_{k \to \infty} f_k = 0$. However, suppose we take $0 \leq f_1 <f_0*\frac{h_0+h_1}{h_0}$, do we have $\lim \inf_{k \to \infty} f_k <0$ for arbitary sequence of discrete distrbution $\{h_k\}$ defined on the $\mathbb{N}$?
Put in another way, I want to know, does there exist a $\{h_k\}$ and the corresponding recurrence relationships, such that for any given two values of initial value $f_1$, $f_2$, we have $\lim_k f_k=0$?

By the way, if someone can suggest a more relevant title for this question, I would also appreciate it.

Your recent edit seems to be missing something? Is the mentioned expression supposed to equal $1$ too?

@Jan, thanks for pointing this out, I added back the missing part this time.

We can rewrite the recursion as
$$
g_kh_{k-1}+g_{k-2}h_{k-2}=g_{k-1}\cdot(h_{k-1}+h_{k-2})
\quad\text{where}\quad
g_k = \frac{f_k}{h_k+h_{k-1}}
$$
which gives a recursion on the differences $g_k-g_{k-1}$:
$$
(g_k-g_{k-1})\cdot h_{k-1} = (g_{k-1}-g_{k-2})\cdot h_{k-2}.
$$
If we let $a=g_0$ and $(g_k-g_{k-1})\cdot h_{k-1}=b$ for all $k>0$ following the above equality, using $g_k-g_{k-1}=b/h_{k-1}$, we get
$$
g_k = a + b\cdot\left(\frac{1}{h_0}+\cdots+\frac{1}{h_{k-1}}\right),
$$
which makes
$$
f_k = (h_k+h_{k-1})\cdot
\left[a + b\cdot\left(\frac{1}{h_0}+\cdots+\frac{1}{h_{k-1}}\right)\right].
$$
As $h_k\rightarrow 0$ when $k\rightarrow\infty$, we get
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} f_k
= b\cdot\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{h_k+h_{k-1}}{h_j}
$$
where the fractions in the sum are all positive and for $j=k-1$ it is greater than 1. If $b\not=0$, that makes $f_k/b>1$ for all sufficiently large $k$, eg when $g_{k-1}/b\ge 0$.
So the only way to get $f_k\rightarrow 0$ is for $b=0$, ie $f_k=(h_k+h_{k-1})f_0/h_0$

Thanks, @Einar Rødland for your nice answer! It also allows us to study how the initial value may affect the asymptotic of the sequence now. Just a small suggestion: I guess you mean $b \equiv (g_1-g_0)*g_0$ and $(g_k-g_{k-1}) = b \frac{h_{0}}{h_{k-1}}$; also, it will be more rigorous to write $|f_k/b|>1$

I intended to define $b$ as the constant value resulting from the preceding equality, ie $(g_k-g_{k-1})h_{k-1}$ which is independent of $k$. I don't quite see where your two equlities come from. And since $f_k/b$ will be dominated by positive terms one of which is greater than 1, the absolute value is not needed.

I see, you are right, I was meaning $(g_k-g_{k-1}) = (g_1-g_{0})\frac{h_0}{h_{k-1}}$ and since $f_k$ will have the same sign with $b$ for large $k$, we don't need to take absolute value.

There is the following easy counterexample. For each nonnegative integer $i$ put $h_{3i}=h_{3i+1}=h_{3i+2}=\frac 1{3\cdot 2^{i+1}}$. Suppose that there exists $f=\lim_{k\to\infty} f_k$.
Then for each natural $k$ divisible by $3$ we have $f_k \cdot\frac{2}{3}+ f_{k-2}\cdot \frac{1}{2} = f_{k-1}$. Taking the limit when $k$ tends to the infinity we obtain $f\cdot \frac{2}{3}+ f\cdot\frac{1}{2} = f$, so $f=0$.

Hi @Alex, thanks for your answer, but I tried itwith the initial value of $f_1=1$ and $f_2=0$ and the sequence is oscillating between -8,-9 and -10, I don't think $\lim_k f_k=0$ holds for all initial value

Actually we have: $\begin{cases} 9 \frac{2}{3} + 8\frac{1}{2}=10 \ 10 \frac{1}{2} + 8\frac{1}{2}=9 \ 9 \frac{1}{3} + 10\frac{1}{2}=8 \end{cases} $

@JakeZHANGShiyu Right, I did not state that $\lim_{k\to\infty} f_k$ always exists. But if it does not exist then we trivially have a counterexample to the claim $\lim_{k\to\infty} f_k<0$, which means that the limit exists and is negative.

I see, thanks for pointing this out, I should have used $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ then
